# How to make URL parameter matching optional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, url-parameters

```
          <Route path="/etc/:id/">
            <Component />
          </Route>
```

I notice, if `:id` is not provided, then it wouldn't match.

How do I change it so that `:id` is optional?

Answer (score 3):

You should add a question mark at the end of the param to make it optional

```
<Route path="/etc/:id?">
    <Component />
</Route>
```

Comment: @free_lions_n_tigers_from_cages, check this out!!